# Call multiple functions from a single route in flask

Tags: python, flask

I have 2 functions in a single direction of page.

> How to access both of them individually? 
>   Now what's happening is, only 1st function is getting called.

The below program is a madeup prototype and my requirement builds on this logic.

```
from bottle import get,post,run,route,request

content1 = ''' 
<html>
<h1>Page 1 function </h1>
<form action='details' method='post'>
<input type = "text" name="uname">
<input type = "submit" >
</form>
</html>'''

content11 = ''' 
<html>
<h1>Page 2 function </h1>
<form action='details' method='post'>
<input type = "text" name="uname">
<input type = "submit" >
</form>
</html>'''

content2 = '''<html><h1>Hello %s </h1></html>'''

@get('/home')
def page1():
    return content1

def page2():
    return content11  

@post('/details')
def page3():
    u_name = str(request.forms.get('uname'))
    return content2 %u_name

run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are asking the question implies you want to provide two separate web pages from the same address. REST doesn't work this way.

You need to provide a second route to access the code in `page2()`

Comment: I totally agree with your point. But if I want to group similar security webpages together , I can put it under 1 address and call the function whichever is needed, that's why I want to have multiple functions under 1 route.

Comment: You could use a route variable to determine which view to render, or you need to track this using a global variable in your program, and then have the single route function return either page depending on that variable.

Comment: I agree with ur point, but can you share en example for it pls ?

Comment: The best way to solve this is to understand what logic is being used to serve either ``content1`` or ``content11``. If you have to check if a user is logged in via some other system, then a simple if/then statement can be used in the ``page1`` function. If it is a login, something like Canister (https://github.com/dagnelies/canister) could solve this for you. (I have not looked at Canister. I have only scanned the list of bottle plugins.)